# AngularJS - preloaded templates not working with directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-template

I want to put all my templates inside script tags and use them from my directives without needing to use ajax requests.

this is my template:

```
<script id="article_row.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <tr>
        <td class="article-id">[[ article.id ]]</td>
        <td>[[ article.title ]]</td>
        <td>[[ article.user_id ]]</td>
        <td>[[ article.created_at ]]</td>
        <td>
            <article-restore id="article.id"></article-restore>
        </td>
    </tr>
</script>
```

this is my directive:

```
app.directive("articleLine", [function(){

    return {

        return: 'E',
        scope: {
            article : "=data"
        },
        templateUrl: "article_row.html"

    };

}]);
```

When loading, I get this error in the console:

```
Error: Failed to load template: article_row.html
```

And I see in the console the browser is trying to get it from `http://localhost/articles/article_row.html`
Instead looking for it in the page, am I doing something wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide a fiddle/plunker. First guess without seeing code is that your `<script>` tag with the template is outside of the `ng-app`, but that's just a guess.

Comment: Its inside the ng-app, after trying for an hour to get it to work I've just moved it above the place where I use the directive in my page and it works (both places are inside the ng-app), any guess why it happens?

Comment: it is because you are trying to use the directive before angular had a chance to load templates. the template has to have been loaded before you call the directive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<article-line data="myData"></article-line>
```

When you put your `articelLine` directive above, this line will be compiled before you include your `article_row.html` ng-template and get the error.

So, you must put `ng-template` before it.